# Wings failed to satart in Pterodactyl

Tags: ubuntu, server

FATAL: [Jul  5 19:48:19.611] failed to configure HTTPS server auto_tls=false                                                                                  error=open /etc/letsencrypt/live/node.atikullah.me/fullchain.pem: no such f                                                                                 ile or directory

Stacktrace:
open /etc/letsencrypt/live/node.atikullah.me/fullchain.pem: no such file or                                                                                  directory
`